# Firebase server timestamp permission denied

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have the following code:

```
        this.afDb.object('/test/location').set(
        {
            meta: {
                'createdAt': firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
            }
        });
```

I get the following error when I execute:

```
FIREBASE WARNING: set at /test/location failed: permission_denied
```

The following however works fine:

```
        this.afDb.object('/test/location').set(
        {
            meta: {
                'createdAt': Date.now().toString()
            }
        });
```

Here are my Firebase Rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.uid !== null",
    ".write": "auth.uid !== null"
  }
}
```

**Update 1**

I changed my rules to the following, but with no success:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what is your security rules ?

Comment: Rules added to OP.

Comment: Can you set your rules to `true` and try again?

Comment: I did and get the same.